# compare two datatable and get differences

Tags: c#, datatable, compare

I have two datatables and I want to get the difference between these two databases based on different columns and copy them to another datatable.

For example

datatable 1

| Code | Name | Age | Money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | User1 | 25 | 68000.00 |
| 456 | User2 | 32 | 23000.00 |
| 963 | User3 | 56 | 75000.00 |
| 852 | User4 | 29 | 13000.00 |

datatable 2

| Code | Name | Age | Money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 963 | User3 | 56 | 75000.00 |
| 456 | User2 | 32 | 26000.58 |
| 123 | User1 | 25 | 59000.63 |
| 852 | User4 | 29 | 13000.00 |
| 741 | UserN | 22 | 15000.56 |

datatable result

| Code | Name | Age | Money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | User2 | 32 | 26000.58 |
| 123 | User1 | 25 | 59000.63 |
| 741 | UserN | 22 | 15000.56 |

I use this code but it does not show the correct result

```
dtr = (from r in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                   where !dt2.AsEnumerable().Any(r2 => r[3].ToString().Trim() == r2[3].ToString().Trim())
                   select r).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq and `Except` to determine:

[The set difference of two sets is defined as the members of the first set that don't appear in the second set.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0)

In the example I am projecting the rows to anonymous types then doing the "except" set operation to obtain the result:

```
var dtrows = dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(rw => new { Code = rw[0], Name = rw[1], Age = rw[2], Money = rw[3] });
var dt2rows = dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(rw => new { Code = rw[0], Name = rw[1], Age = rw[2], Money = rw[3] });

dt2rows.Except(dtrows)
```

Comment: Not a good solution. The age column may change. I just want to show the result based on the money column or another column

Comment: @phpDeveloper Then two things. You should say that in the question, and second, just exclude age from the projection.